# pathfinder perception stacking

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, pathfinder-beginner-box

A rogue elf gets a +2 to perception in the misc box for his racial ability.
A rogue has perception as a class skill, if she puts 1 skill point in it at level 1, she should get +3 in the misc box?

do these stack, or does the rogue only get the highest value (+3)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**They stack.**

The misc box on the character sheet is a place for all the miscellaneous modifiers the character gets. Of course, if you were to get two bonuses of the same type they would not stack, but in this case they are different - +2 *racial* bonus, +3 *class skill* bonus = +5 in the "misc" box.